# Unknown Dot notation for vector functions regarding waves across a surface.

Tags: notation, vectors, inner-products

I came across this notation where the equations were related to waves across a liquid surface as a consequence of moving bodies within that liquid. Of course I'm familiar with dot products, but this notation used:

$$
\mathbf{r}.\mathbf{k}
$$

where I've always seen dot products represented as:

$$
r \cdot k
$$

Also, given the context that I came across these equations, it's entirely possible that there was some sort of parsing error that resulted in the latex 'dot' being interpreted as a period, but I'm still leaning towards this meaning either a regular dot product or some function that I'm unaware of.

Any help would be phenomenal.
Thanks!

Comment: what is the difference if not the font? As long as it makes sense it is just a dot product that is not written in math mode

Comment: Some authors write dot products like that. It can't be helped.

Comment: So, by what you wrote, we may assume that it is a text written in $\LaTeX$?

Comment: It is. To be clear, I'd love to post the article but it's behind a private, paid service. But yes, and that's what was confusing. Not only was the article written in Latex, the author used some external packages as well, so I assume they're familiar enough with how to write latex. The other possibility, because it was hosted in a pretty old web app, I'm wondering if there was a parsing error displaying certain latex symbols appropriately once rendered to html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely the standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^3$. It is common to see $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}$ in physics where $\vec{k}$ is the [angular wave vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector) that encodes the wavelength ($\lambda = \frac{2 \pi}{\lvert \vec{k} \rvert}$) and wavefront normal ($\hat{k}$) of a sinusoidal traveling wave. In fact, $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}$ should be thought of as the spatial contribution to the phase observed at a position $\vec{r}$ (in general, the phase of a sinusoidal traveling wave is of the form $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t + \phi$ where $\omega$ is angular frequency, $t$ is time, and $\phi$ is a phase offset). The meaning of the dot product $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}$ is readily explained when viewed as $\lvert \vec{k} \rvert \hat{k} \cdot \vec{r}$, where $\hat{k} \cdot \vec{r}$ is the component of the position vector in the direction of phase propagation and $\lvert \vec{k} \rvert$ is the proportionality constant between this distance and the spatial contribution to phase.